# How to create Google Maps SDK API key for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, xcode6, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have decided to use Google Maps SDK for iOS. 
There's an instruction for obtaining the API key through  Google APIs Console:

1. Create an API project in the Google APIs Console.
2. Select the Services pane in your API project, and enable the Google Maps SDK for iOS. This displays the Google Maps Terms of Service.
3. Select the API Access pane in the console, and click Create new iOS key.
4. Enter one or more bundle identifiers as listed in your application's .plist file, such as com.example.myapp.
5. Click Create.
6. In the API Access page, locate the section Key for iOS apps (with bundle identifiers) and note or copy the 40-character API key.

But I have no such thing as **Google Maps SDK for iOS** in **Services**. Does Google no longer support iOS API keys?

Comment: I know that this doesn't specifically answer your question, but I feel bad not telling you: use Leaflet instead. You're going to save a lot of money and time that way.

Comment: Another option you can look into is building a web version of your google maps based application (just the map portion), and pulling it in via `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start:

> Important: The SDK is available for download, and you may register for
>   access to an API key. Before you can sign up for an API key, your
>   Google account will have to be enabled to access the Google Maps SDK
>   for iOS. We'll contact you as API keys are made available.

So, you need to register, and then wait until Google get back to you (which may take a long time).

**UPDATE:**

It looks like the SDK is now available to everyone.